# Django DRF Image store private for user only on S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for storing user uploaded images to S3 and in S3 i can see that images are public accessible using the URL.

**My concern over here is there any best way to secure this images and restrict them for owner of that image only to view it.**

I am using Heroku to deploy my DRF API Framework but i see this as security concern for my user who are uploading image files to S3 bucket.

I am trying to isolate user images by their name it self.But still it is public so i can access this images for another user just figure it out there name.

Here is S3 URL for media Images

```
https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/media/persons/niravjoshi/20181218152410.jpg
```

Here is my **settings.py for Django**

```
import os
import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#SECRET_KEY = 'feufm)u(pvsvb%&_%%*)p_bpa+sv8zt$#_-do5q3(vou-j*d#p'

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #Django Project Apps
    'persons',
    'rest_framework',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    #'social_django',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
AWS_REGION = os.environ.get('AWS_REGION', '')  # e.g. eu-west-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET', '')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN", "")

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'DjangoE2ISAapi.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)




STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
django_heroku.settings(locals())

from DjangoE2ISAapi.restconf.main import *
```

**Here is my storage_backends.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_STATIC_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

**Here is my Person model.py.**

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
# Create your models here.

def upload_file(instance,filename):
    import os
    from django.utils.timezone import now
    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "persons/{user}/{filename}".format(user=instance.UserName, filename=now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+filename_ext.lower())



class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        list_values=list(self.values('UserName','PersonId','PersonName','Person_Image','Person_sex','Person_BDate'))
        print (list_values)
        return json.dumps(list_values,sort_keys=True,indent=1,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return PersonQuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)


class Person(models.Model):
    UserName = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    PersonId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PersonName = models.CharField("person's first name", max_length=30,null=False)
    Person_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_file,null=True, blank=True)
    SEX = (('M','Male'),('F','Female'), ('N','None'), )
    Person_sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SEX,null=False)
    Person_BDate = models.DateField(null=False)
    Person_CDate =  models.DateField(null=False,auto_now_add=True)
    objects = PersonManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.PersonName) or ""

    def serialize(self):
        data={
            'UserName': self.UserName,
            'PersonId': self.PersonId,
            'PersonName': self.PersonName,
            'Person_Image':self.Person_Image,
            'Person_sex': self.Person_sex,
            'Person_Bdate': self.Person_BDate
        }
        data = json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True,indent=1,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return data

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.UserName
```

[image]

**Here is response of Person API View:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `uuid` field to every user like.

```
import uuid

class Person(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUID(default=uuid.uuid4)
    ....
```

You can set it as primary key as well instead of AutoField.

and put that unique `uuid` into URL instead of `name` in order to look like:

```
https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/media/persons/b3810ec3-dd9d-4f11-a1e1-47835c0058ec/20181218152410.jpg
```

That image will be still public, but it's impossible to access image if you don't know uuid of particular user.

If you want more secure solution not depending on URL only you need to add some Authentication logic.

Comment: thank you for your input. i have given thought about the using UUID since UUID are difficult to guess that would do the work ..but i am looking forward with your suggestion on Authentication logic for URL can you please elaborate it.

Comment: [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is a terrible idea, and that's all this answer provides.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for boto's ACLs are [here](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#setting-getting-the-access-control-list-for-buckets-and-keys). I suggest just using the `private` "canned policy" -- since your users don't have S3 accounts anyway, it's by far the simplest idea. Your app will of course have to keep track of which user "owns" which files (which should be a very, very simple Django model!).

In order to enforce users only being able to download through your own application, just pass a small value to the expires_in parameter when generating the URL. Users will only get a valid download link through your application, and that link will be invalidated after their download.

Here is an example of the code used to generate the link for downloading :

```
@login_required
def download_document(request, file_id):
    '''
     Request handler to download file
    '''
    file = Document.objects.get(pk=file_id)
    s3 = get_aws_s3_client() #function to create s3 session
    download_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'get_object',
        Params= {'Bucket': file.bucket_name, 'Key': file.key},
        ExpiresIn=5, #the url won't be valid after only 5 seconds
    )
    return redirect(download_url)
```

You can go further and make the view valid only for the file owner by adding this code :

```
if file.owner == request.user : 
   return redirect(download_url)
else :
   # render 403.html  since access denied.
```

**Edit :** 
As requested, this solution requires using a specific model to store informations related to each document. 
The model will look similar to this :

```
class Image(models.Model):
    customer     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    key          = models.CharField(max_length=120) #uuid64 will be stored here and used for s3 urls
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    size         = models.FloatField()
    human_size   = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    filetype     = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    fextension   = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    bucket_name  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    region       = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    s3link       = models.CharField(max_length=170, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uploaded     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I can't discuss parts related to serialization since I have never used DRF.

Comment: Hi Alouani... Thanks for your reply. So according to your suggestion we should have another table which tracks the URLs for each user for uploaded image. Then we should have this logic can you please elaborate on the model and with respect to Django Rest Framework /serializer and API